# account's balance at a point of time in AggCat

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, customer-account-data-api

Is there anyway to obtain an account's info including account's balance at a point of time? Basically, I need to get the account's balance at the beginning of month and end of month for accounting purposes. However, a cron job to update account's info at the beginning/end of month may fail for various reasons, in which case there is no way to retrieve account's balance at beginning/end of month anymore!

Comment: in IPP-AggCat, getAccount is the only API available to get any info related to account. Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/customer_account_data_api/0020_api_documentation/0025_getaccount

It is a GET request. So, there is no provision to pass any special filter as part of the request body.

Comment: Given what you said, there is no way to get the account' balance on a particular date if that date is in the past? Then do you have any suggestion wrt my concern above?

Answer (score 2):

We do not have a mechanism to capture the value at a specific time as you are asking but provide a balance each time you capture the transactions.  If you capture a day later you can always perform a reverse running balance using the current balance - the transactions that occured between the data you wish to display.

Example:
August 1st:

- $5.00 Transaction to McDonalds
- $3.00 Transaction to Ralphs

Balance on August 2nd:
$35.00

Calculate Balance for the 1st.
$35 + 5 + 3= $43.00 balance at start of month.

You add the debits and subtract the credits and you can obtain the value you are seeking.

Comment: Ben, I just submitted a support ticket on this issue.  How do you determine what starting balance to use (availableBalanceAmount or balanceAmount)?  Sometimes they are different and its not always the case to use one.